# How to Compare image by Link Array in Angular

Tags: typescript, angular7, image-compression

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-compare-images?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

*In given link image details are provide*

**But, I have the an array of images link and I want to compare them and find the duplicate images**

**

```
image = [
    'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ca/76/0b/ca760b70976b52578da88e06973af542.jpg',
    'https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/500px/983794168.jpg',
    'https://cdn.eso.org/images/thumb300y/eso1322a.jpg',
    'https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/500px/983794168.jpg',
    'https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-74343235,width-640,resizemode-4/74343235.jpg',
    'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ca/76/0b/ca760b70976b52578da88e06973af542.jpg'
  ];
```

**

Comment: Small hint, since your `charsMap` property is static, you can define it outside of component